# Is there a symbol or way of writing "in between" or "up to" for a year on a timeline graph?

Tags: typography, information-graphics, chart-design

I am making a timeline and every point is one specific year (1965, 1975, 1982, 1985, 1986) except for one point which is a range "1987-2014". Having one data point that's double the size of the others breaks the design and I'd like to show something like "...2014" or "< 2014" or "–2014" to use less space but I'm not sure what's correct or most readable.

Comment: How about '87-'14?

Comment: Let the break happen if every point presents something which characterizes a time period. Most of the time periods are one year long, but the one is 28 years. Let's assume you have a bar chart of the number of the months in the given periods. All one year long periods have a 12 units long bar, but the one has a 336 unit long bar in linear scale. Nobody is surprised when they see that the peak is based on longer time.

Comment: What happens if you use vertical (not stacked) year labels? Then the horizontal interval between the years (and data points) is not irregular.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, the symbol `≤` can mean between.

`a ≤ x ≤ d` -- `x` must between `a` and `d` possibly including either `a` or `d`

So... `≤ 2014` perhaps

However, for general purposes I don't think using `<` or `-` is a problem.

Heck you could possibly consider a tilde, `~`. Tilde means "approximately".

Comment: Where does ≤ mean ‘between’? I know it to mean ‘less than or equal to’ or ‘is a subgroup of’ in mathematics, but not ‘between’…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet it *is* essentially less than or equal to. It can also be translated as between in some cases. `a ≤ x ≤ d` -- `x` must between a and d possibly including either a or d, whereas `a < x < d` would mean x is larger than a but smaller than d, and *not* a or d. At least that's always been my understanding. Perhaps I'm incorrect.